# form data transferring issue through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have created a form using ajax but I am trying to post its data like normal form(without ajax). But its data is not going to transfer to the other page. If anybody can help me I'll be grateful to you.

```
$('body').on('click','a.btn_details',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var _id = $(this).attr('id');
    var _data = {'action': 'product_details','product_id':_id};
    $.ajax({
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': '../common/products.php',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'data': _data,
        'success': function (resp) {
            var _about = resp.product_info.details;
            var product_attributes = resp.attributes;
            _about += '<div class="form" style="margin-top:30px;"><form name="frmOrder" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="addtocart.php">';
             var options;
             var total_opt=0;
             /*alert(resp.attribute_options);
             return false;*/
            for(var i=0;i<product_attributes.length;i++)
            {
                options = resp.attribute_options[product_attributes[i].id];
                total_opt = options.length;

                if(total_opt)
                {

                    _about += '<div class="form-group">';
                    _about += '<label for="label" class="col-md-3 control-label">'+product_attributes[i].name+':</label>';
                    _about += '<div class="col-md-9 inputGroupContainer"><div class="input-group"><select name="options[]" class="form-control selcart">';

                    for(var j=0;j<total_opt;j++)
                    {
                        //alert(options[j].name);
                       _about += '<option value="'+options[j].id+'">'+options[j].name+'</option>';
                    }
                    _about += '</select></div></div>';
                    _about += '</div>';
                }
            }
            _about += '<div class="form-group"><label for="label" class="col-md-3 control-label">&nbsp;</a></label>';
            _about += '<div class="col-md-9 inputGroupContainer"><div class="input-group"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" value="Add to Cart" /></div></div></div></form></div>';

            $("#product_name").html(resp.product_info.name);
            $("#about_product").html(_about);
            $("#pic_product").html("<img class='media-object img-thumbnail img-responsive' width='350' src='<?php echo $site_path?>upload_prdimgs/"+resp.product_info.image_name+"' />");                        
        },
       complete: function(){
         $('#prd_list_cont').fadeOut("slow");
         $('#prd_det_cont').fadeIn("slow");
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: - Doing it on my way, I would instead show and hide the div containing the form, then populate it with the data that i get from your ajax response, i think it would be a little cleaner and easier to troubleshoot, Give it a try,

Comment: I've edited the  code but facing same problem. :(

Comment: 1. Make sure your function is called - add some breakpoint, console.log() or alert 2. Make sure ajax request is done. Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I've fixed this issue some other way.